# What is the probability that Tom won a math competition?

Tags: probability

The problem:

> Probability of Tom winning a math contest is $5\%$. Probability of the
>   Tom winning a chemistry contest is $12\%$. Probability of Tom not winning anything is $100 - 12 - 5 = 83\%$. Now suppose we know that Tom has won one contest (either math or chemistry, but not both). What is the probability that the contest Tom won is math?

Will I be correct to say that the answer to this question is$\frac{5}{5+12}  \approx 29.4\%$?

Comment: Is there 0% probability that he wins both contests ?

Comment: @WW1 Well, maybe not necessarily, but we know that he one exactly one contest, so we know that it's probability 0 that he won both contests.

Comment: @WW1, yes, it is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I like to think about it by thinking 5/17-ths of the space of all ways Tom wins exactly one competition (measured by probability) is made up of him winning a math competition. We're in that space, so those are his odds.